# How to display items of dictionary on different labels in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net coding and trying to get the keys and values of dictionary to be displayed on different labels using loop.
I have 10 labels with id Label1,Label2,...., Label10.
How do i display the keys and values on different label using loops ?

```
Dictionary<string, int> numbers_of_items = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        numbers_of_items.Add("Kettle",30);
        numbers_of_items.Add("juicer", 40);
        numbers_of_items.Add("toaster", 50);
        numbers_of_items.Add("microwave", 60);
        numbers_of_items.Add("dishwaher", 70);

        for (int i =0; 1<numbers_of_items.Count;i++)
        {
            // I am stuck here. Dont know how to set each key and value to 
            //different labels
        }
```

Comment: can your `dictionary` have more items?

Comment: Is this Model View Controller or Web Forms?

Comment: It is webforms @Greg

Comment: @Gonzalo it can have more items also. But its about fitting that data on labels using loops

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Code behind:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in myDictionary)
{
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Text = entry.Value;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```